# Keepers explained in Defi

Tags: chainlink, defi, chainlink-automation

So I have been working on a fork for GMX. In the end it gets stuck on off chain keepers (which was supposedly fixed by Chainlinks upkeep). Can someone please explain what exactly is happening? I dont need the code I just need to understand how keepers fit in for a transaction and how they're set and used.

I see that they're used in other projects as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chainlink automation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/introduction/)(previously known as Chainlink keepers) is a solution of smart contract conditional automation.

It is pretty straightforward to understand and use Chainlink automation(keepers). For every consumer contract(the contract which you want to automate), there are 2 functions that have to be implemented  - `checkUpkeep` and `performUpkeep`.

The condition([time-based](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/job-scheduler/) or [custom logic](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/register-upkeep/)) should be defined in `checkUpkeep`, and execution logics defined in `performUpkeep`.

With the 2 functions set, Chainlink node(oracle node is off-chain) could check the status by calling function `checkUpkeep`, and call `performUpkeep` when the pre-defined condition is met. This is the basic workflow and you can also learn more about Chainlink Automation from [master class](https://chain.link/automation?_ga=2.208152341.648473562.1675135098-852897474.1652875455#masterclass) provided by Chainlink labs.

Comment: Thank you. The masterclass link was very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

keepers are a fundamental piece of the web3 ecosystem and help contracts execute transactions without manual intervention.
Keepers are bots checking and executing when specific conditions are met. They live off-chain and his role is to initiate the transactions previously defined.

Imagine that you want to execute a trade when a certain eth/usd threshold has been reached; then you would use a keeper to watch the chain and execute the trade when this happens

I wrote last summer an article explaining the different automation solutions:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/smart-contract-automation-state-of-the-art-hack-view-c153944b1a02 as well as how they can help also with randomness solutions https://medium.com/coinmonks/schedule-randomness-with-gelato-and-witnet-api3-chainlink-vrf-1ebc0aac37d

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is interesting I’ll look deeper into it

Comment: Glad to have helped!